# In a CustomValidationAttribute-invoked method how can I store some of the information for the method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Max length per string is 200
/// </summary>
[CustomValidation(typeof(ProjectPixelValidator), "IsProjectPixelCollectionValid")]
public IEnumerable<string> ProjectPixels { get; set; }
```

To determine if it is valid, I have to call out to the database to get validation information specific to the current user.

Sample of the actual method:

```
public const int MaxPixelLength = 200;
public static ValidationResult IsProjectPixelCollectionValid(IEnumerable<string> projectPixels, ValidationContext context)
{ /* ... omitted code ... */ 
    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

If it is valid, I would have to call back to the same method to get data that was needed to validate. I realize I could stick it in one of the 2-3 Cache systems that exist in asp.net (`MemoryCache` and the like), but I was hoping to find **something more request-specific**.

In MVC, as I recall, I would I could just add it to the route data dictionary.

Can I store this information somewhere that tells web API it can use that data as one of the parameters for the method, or somewhere that is only alive for the length of the request the action can call into?

I have a preference for options that allow or enable method-injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything that should be stored for the duration of the HTTP request inside a `Properties` dictionary on the `HttpRequestMessage`.  You have access to the current `HttpRequestMessage` in all Web API components - message handlers, filters, controllers, even formatters, so that place is very suitable.

It's an `IDictionary<string,object>` so can hold any object, and Web API itself stores loads of information there too (such as error level detail, reference to HttpContext, flag whether the request was local etc).

You can also use some extensions methods to help you deal with adding and retrieving stuff from that dictionary:

```
public static class HttpRequestMessageExtensions
{
    public static void Add(this HttpRequestMessage request, string key, object o)
    {
        request.Properties.Add(key, o);
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this HttpRequestMessage request, string key)
    {
        object result;
        if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(key, out result))
        {
            if (result is T)
            {
                return (T) result;
            }
            try
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof (T));
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException) {}
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

[Reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.properties(v=vs.118).aspx).

[Code reference](https://github.com/filipw/apress-recipes-webapi/blob/master/Chapter%2005/5-12/Apress.Recipes.WebApi/Apress.Recipes.WebApi/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs)